# ACF Monthly data

Tags: r, time-series

I have 275 row sales data. I want to create ACF from this time series data. ACF should be from 1 till circa 69 (275/4 in books)

`par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(3,3,1,0)+.5, mgp=c(1.6,.6,0))
ts.plot(sales_ts_ohne_na,col="blue")
acf(sales_ts_ohne_na)`

[image]

Comment: set `lag.max=69` in `acf()`. This should make the plot go to 5.75 periods (i.e 69/12, where 12 is the sampling frequency of your time series).

Comment: are there some ways that the acf show till 69?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep in mind the sampling frequency of your time series. I assume it is 12, as you have monthly data.

In `acf()`, if you set `lag.max=69`, you will get the acf for lags up to 69. But as duration is counted in periods, it will extend to 5.75 instead, which is 69/12. If you want the x-axis to count samples instead, you can just set the sampling frequency to 1.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sin(seq(0, pi*2*25, by=pi/(12/2)))
x.ts <- ts(x + rnorm(length(x)), f=12)

par(mfrow=c(3, 1))
acf(x.ts)
acf(x.ts, lag.max=69)
acf(ts(x.ts, f=1), lag.max=69)
```

[image]